# Use multiple devices with an ISP with captive portal

Tags: networking, router, isp, mac-address, captive-portal

Here are the facts that will help you understand the scenario:

1. The ISP provides wireless broadband. It gives a device(installed on the roof) from which a LAN wires runs to your computer.
2. The ISP utilizes [captive portal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal) to control access to internet. Every user logins with a username/password and then accesses the internet. The ISP limits the number of simultaneous logins to a specified number(usually 2).
3. Until now I only used the computer to connect to the internet. So the LAN wire from the roof directly came to the computer. Now I have decided to use the internet in more devices using a wireless router.
4. When I connect the LAN wire from the roof to a wireless router, and connect any device to the router via wire or wifi, each device gets a separate login page and run independent of each other's connection. My point being that at any given point of time, I can only browse internet on only 2 devices.
5. The ISP utilizes MAC address filtering to recognize  a connection. That is every device is uniquely identified by its MAC address.

Now my questions/problems are:

1. How can I force the router to only use 1 connection and share that connection over all the connected devices. I searched about this and I think that it would be possible with MAC address spoofing.
2. wish the login page to be displayed to the first device that connect to the wireless router and the other devices that connect later to have a working live internet connection.

The wireless router is : [TP-LINK TL-WR740N 150Mbps Wireless N Router](http://www.tp-link.com/lk/products/details/?model=TL-WR740N#spec) and supports DD-WRT if required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even a good, working solution, might fail in your case.

The danger lies in the fact that some networks are capable of identifying a node acting as a NAT router, by checking on the decrease of the TTL for ping packets. If this is the case for your provider, then no solution can be found.

You may check whether this is your case by setting up a wifi hotspot on your connected pc, connecting to it with your phone for instance, and checking whether the phone has Internet access. If it does, you may try one of the solutions below. Setting up a wifi hotspot is easy, it just depends on your OS, you may Google for it.

Mac Spoofing is a possibility. Mac Spoofing exists on many commercial routers, an is intended to make it possible to buy a new home router when your ISP only allows one MAC address to connect to its network. Setup the router to use your ethernet MAC address, connect via your pc and register to the captive portal, then unhook your ethernet cable and plug it into the router.

Alternatively, you may setup a pc to act as the router (this is easiest for *Nix OSes). This has the advantage that you can register the pc directly on the captive portal, without having to unhook the ethernet cable: just sit at the pc, open a browser, login to the captive portal, and from now on all devices connected to the pc will be able to navigate the Internet (provided your ISP does not employ the NAT-discovery technique mentioned above).

As for dd-wrt, I do not think it helps. DD-WRT is mostly used to setup captive portals, not to access them. Thus it has no facility to access one, from the command line or otherwise.